# Multiple tags for testCafe test

Tags: meta-tags, testcafe

Is it possibly configure tags for a test in TestCafe that one test will belong to more than one meta group.
Example:

```
test  .meta('group', 'smoke-test')  .meta('group', 'main-functionality')
('test name', async t => {
```

CLI:

```
"smoke-test": "testcafe chrome:headless e2e/test  --test-meta group=smoke-test
"main-functionality": "testcafe chrome:headless e2e/test  --test-meta group=main-functionality",
```

Right now it runs only for the first group 'smoke-test' and ignore this test when I run group of tests for main-functionality

research on line resources but did not find a define answer yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`meta` is an `object` and it can't contain two properties with the same `key`. It means you must come up with another `key` for another metadata. It will work in this way:

```js
test
  .meta('group', 'smoke-test')
  .meta('main-group', 'main-functionality')
  ('My first test', async t => {
    //...
  });
```

```
{
  "smoke-test": "testcafe chrome:headless e2e/test  --test-meta group=smoke-test,
  "main-functionality": "testcafe chrome:headless e2e/test  --test-meta main-group=main-functionality",
}
```